# Getting "[error] [converse] Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" when defining multiple actions in Wit.ai

Tags: node.js, wit.ai

I am trying to define multiple actions coding in Node.js in Wit.ai, and I get the error -

"[error] [converse] Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Does anyone know why I got this, and What's the proper way to define multiple actions?

Thanks!

```
const actions = {
    say(sessionId, context, message, cb) {
        console.log(message);
        cb();
    },
    merge(sessionId, context, entities, message, cb) {
        // Retrieve the location entity and store it into a context field
        `enter code here`
        const loc = firstEntityValue(entities, 'location');
        if (loc) {
            context.loc = loc;
        }
        cb(context);
    },
    error(sessionId, context, error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    },
    ['forecast-all'](sessionId, context, cb) {
        // Here should go the api call, e.g.:
        `enter code here`
        context.forecast = getWeather(context.loc)
        cb(context);
    },

    ['forecast-feelslike'](sessionId, context, cb) {
        // Here should go the api call, e.g.:
        context.forecast = getFeelslike(context.loc)
        cb(context);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about answer but it seems you have used string replace method on the variable which not defined properly.

I can help you better, if you can show your code.